# Cannot start Mongo DB. Unable to lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I installed MongoDB with Homebrew. I also created a directory called /data/db.

However, when I run mongod, I get this message:

```
exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock Resource temporarily unavailable. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
```

I doubt it's already running because I just installed it. I've quit the terminal and rebooted, but it doesn't help.

Here's a screenshot of my terminal

[image]

Any idea what I need to do? Thanks!

Comment: are you sure that ```/data/db/``` has permissions of user, otherwise try you ```sudo mongod```

Comment: Yes, tried that. I get this: shutting down with code:100

Comment: try you this ```sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/db``` then ```sudo chown $USER /data/db```

Comment: tried that too. no dice :-(

Comment: Got the same error but mine was caused by not shutting down mongo properly. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857781/what-is-the-use-of-the-mongo-lock-file

Answer (score 0):

try stopping the mongod service using the command

```
brew services stop mongod
```