# Mongodb not starting as normal user

Tags: mongodb, usergroups, systemctl

My MongoDB server is not starting on command `mongod`

Typing `sudo service mongodb status` yeilds

```
mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-11-28 20:08:25 IST; 2s ago
Process: ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 29675 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

System service:

```
#/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

mongod conf:

```
#/etc/mongod.conf
storage:
    dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
    journal:
        enabled: true

systemLog:
    destination: file
    logAppend: true
    path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

However if i am running `sudo -u mongodb mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf` it runs.
Also if I run `sudo mongod` the server tries to start but the storage path is `/data/db/` which I haven't created.

`mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf` gives the below error

```
[main] Failed global initialization: FileNotOpen: Failed to open "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"
```

I had run `chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb`

Permissions:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb  4096 Nov 28 20:19 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
drwxr-xr-x  4 mongodb mongodb  20480 Nov 28 21:32 /var/lib/mongodb
```

Now whenever I need MongoDB server I have to run it with  `sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/`

It seems like a permission issue for me. But I cannot figure how to fix this out?

Comment: Double check the `/var/lib/mongodb` and `/var/log/mongodb` folders permissions.

Comment: ```drwxr-xr-x  4 mongodb     mongodb     20480 Nov 28 21:32 /var/lib/mongodb``` and ```drwxr-xr-x  2 mongodb mongodb     4096 Nov 28 20:19 /var/log/mongodb```

Comment: Maybe the lock.file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857781/what-is-the-use-of-the-mongo-lock-file

Comment: @Björn Nope, the lock was not the issue. I still am struggling with the issue. Now whenever I need MongoDB server I have to run it with  `sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/`